# 夏目漱石　「心」　Confused by use of いた in apparent relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, literature

Continuing to work my way through 心, progressing a little bit more each day. Though I've been reading past this point, I was not as confident in my interpretation of this sentence in retrospect as I would like:

> 学校の授業が始まるにはまだ大分日数があるので鎌倉におってもよし、帰ってもよいという境遇にいた私は、当分元の宿に留まる覚悟をした。

My current interpretation goes something like this: "Given that there were a great many days yet before classes started, and in the circumstances being in Kamakura or going back home were both agreeable to me, I presently resolved to stay at my original lodging."

I am assuming that the 'おって' here is from おる, though that's confusing in light of the いた that follows. Furthermore, I'm working from the assumption that the いた just before 私 has a literal meaning of 'the me who was . . . ', but this is the part I'm least confident about. Note that I am also assuming that 留まる is here an archaic use of kanji for 泊まる. Any corrections would be most appreciated.

Comment: 「留まる」は「ある場所から移動しない」、「泊まる」は「宿泊施設などで夜を過ごす」という意味で使います。　「留まる」is for >1a."To continue to be in a place or condition", 「泊まる」is for >1b."To remain or sojourn as a guest or lodger" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stay

Comment: 三省堂 大辞林 「留まる」 http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%95%99%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B　>(1)人が，移動せずにその場所にいる。 「泊まる」 http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B3%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B >(1)自分の家以外の所で夜を明かす。

Comment: `留まる is here an archaic use of kanji for 泊まる` But... here it's read as [留]{とど}まる, not [留]{と}まる, no? 「[留]{とど}まる」と「[留]{と}まる」は少し意味が違うので・・

Answer (score 2):

> 学校の授業が始まるにはまだ大分日数があるので鎌倉におってもよし、帰ってもよいという境遇にいた私は、当分元の宿に留まる覚悟をした。
>
> 学校の授業が始まるにはまだ大分日数があるので
>   （私は）鎌倉におってもよし、帰ってもよい
>   という境遇（状態あるいは心境）にいた
>   （そんな）私は、当分元の宿に留まる覚悟をした。

「鎌倉におっても　よし」は、「鎌倉にいても　よし」あるいは「鎌倉に留まっても　よし」の意味。

「という境遇にいた私」は、「と言う境遇（状態、心境）の中にいた　私」なので、

肉体としての私が、滞在していたのは、「鎌倉」だが、

気持ちとしての私が、「いた」のは、「おってもよいし、帰ってもよいという境遇（心境）」

主人公は「当分元の宿に留まる覚悟をした」とあるが、先ず「当分元の宿に留まる」のは、積極的に「元の宿に留まる」のではなく、「おってもよいし、帰ってもよい」の２つの選択肢の一方を消極的に選択した。しかも"帰る"のではないんで、”そのまま居る”方を選択した。そのニュアンスが「留まる(keep staying)」になっている。

ちなみに、「留まることにした」ではなく、「留まる覚悟をした」と「覚悟をした」のであるから、「留まる」方を選択するのにも、何か"困難"か”心理的な苦痛”があるのだろう。それはこの引用の前を読まないと分からない。